# How to interface with a custom office addin using pywin32

Tags: python, ms-office, pywin32

I'm trying to interface with a custom add-in for powerpoint using python 3. Specifically think-cell, a charting tool. I need to use just one function documented here: https://www.think-cell.com/en/support/manual/exceldataautomation.shtml

I can successfuly use pywin32 to connect to powerpoint and get a reference to the addin

```
import win32com.client as win32

def ppt():
    return win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('PowerPoint.Application')

def excel():
    return win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
e = excel()
p = ppt()
thinkcell = p.COMAddIns("thinkcell.addin").Object
```

However when I call `thinkcell.UpdateChart(slide, "Chart24", r)` (slide and r defined elsewhere) I get:
`AttributeError: <unknown>.UpdateChart`.

I believe this to mean that the issue is there's no python interface written for the think-cell addin or that the addin is not registered in such a way that the object can call its functions.

How can I resolve this? If I need to write an interface that allows calling UpdateChart, what would that look like?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried some simple actions as:

```
p.Visible = True
presentation=p.Presentations.Add()
slide = presentation.Slides.Add(1, 12)
myDiamond = slide.Shapes.AddShape(4, Top=100,Left=100, Width=20, Height=20)

presentation.SaveAs(“C:\\Temp\\myPowerPoint”,1)
```

Also, Did you tried with:

```
p = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
```

Comment: Yes, regular powerpoint functions work. My question is about interfacing with add-ins. Using Dispatch rather than EnsureDispatch did not affect anything.